Issue with Phi-3 model in Jupyter Notebook
I am facing an issue while working with the Phi-3 model in Jupyter Notebook. I am getting an error related to the Phi3Config object not having the attribute _attn_implementation.
Here is the relevant code snippet:
# Load model directly
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/Phi-3-mini-128k-instruct", trust_remote_code=True)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/Phi-3-mini-128k-instruct", trust_remote_code=True)

This should've loaded model.
The code successfully loads the tokenizer and the model, but when I try to use the model, I encounter the following error:
AttributeError: 'Phi3Config' object has no attribute '_attn_implementation'
I have already loaded the necessary files, including tokenizer_config.json, tokenizer.model, tokenizer.json, added_tokens.json, and special_tokens_map.json.
Here is the complete output for reference:
Fils

I have this same error. Did you find a solution?

@RylanSchaeffer no I did not but It worked when I used a smaller model which was fine for my use case

applying these modifications might get your code up and running.
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/Phi-3-mini-128k-instruct")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "microsoft/Phi-3-mini-128k-instruct",
    torch_dtype="auto",
    trust_remote_code=True,
)


unfortunately this did not work and i got the same error
